# GlassFish NoClassDefFoundError - Netbeans project

Tags: netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish, noclassdeffounderror

I'm sometimes getting NoClassDefFoundError after deploying web application in Netbeans (6.9.1). It's actually  problem with Netbeans not deploying entire project (not copying class files or other relevant files), but only part of it.

Running "Clean & Build" a few times and/or copying rest of the files solves the problem, but it's very inconvenient.

Anyone knows the cause or solution of this problem?

Comment: I "resolved" this problem by complete reinstallation of Netbeans (and glassfish)... So far the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your Netbeans cache, or check out the bug fixes for Netbeans 7.

The cache is at ~/.netbeans/6.9/var/cache. I found instructions to just delete the index/ folder in the cache, but that didn't seem to be enough.

EDIT: Deleting the entire cache didn't seem to resolve it, either.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not much clear but,

I suggest to add your required jar files in Netbeans library then import the library into your project..

If this does not work then i'll be glad to having the complete situation and errors to be written here...